# Socket is not receiving all the bytes C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have a problem at work with sockets. I have a client to the server should send a screenshot. The problem is that the server is not receiving all the bytes from the array, which is sent by the client.Constantly lacks 255 bytes (checked back several times). Accordingly, on the server side I can not perform the conversion from byte array back into an image.

Client sends data to the server:

```
byte[] bytesforSend = ConvertBitmapToByteArray(GetScreenImage());
client.Send(bytesforSend, bytesforSend.Length, 0);
```

Server recieves data from the client:

```
int lenght = cl.socket.Receive(bytes);
```

Perhaps all very easy to solve but I'm working with sockets the first time and I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: Are you using TCP sockets? TCP sockets are *streaming*, and don't have any fixed start or end of messages, there are no *packets* in the meaning tha UDP have it. Therefore you need to receive in a loop until you have received all data. Also, if you're reading or writing an image, it needs to be done in binary mode, not text mode.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I'm using TCP socket. Trying to recieve in a loop. `List<byte[]> recievingBytes = new List<byte[]>();
            List<int> lenghts = new List<int>();

            int lenght;

            do
            {
                lenght = cl.socket.Receive(bytes);
                recievingBytes.Add(bytes);
                lenghts.Add(lenght);
            } while (lenght != 0); ` What i'm doing wrong? First array in the list has elements, second one 0...

Comment: I don't see how what you're saying can make sense - since `bytes` is a `Byte[]`, and you don't seem to be re-creating it, you would be adding the *same* array object to `receivingBytes` multiple times, and its contents should be whatever's been left in there by several successive `Receive` calls overwriting each other.

Comment: Closing question because code is incomplete. Provide complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Let me paste here the code that you have written in a comment:

```
List<byte[]> recievingBytes = new List<byte[]>(); 
List<int> lenghts = new List<int>();
int lenght; do
{ 
    lenght = cl.socket.Receive(bytes); 
    recievingBytes.Add(bytes); 
    lenghts.Add(lenght); 
} while (lenght != 0);
```

The most likely problem here (I saw a similar issue in a commercial library that communicated with a camera) is that you are assuming that the all the data will reach its destination at the same time, but this could not be true depending on the networking conditions or on how the client is actually sending the data.

Assume for example that the client sends a 2048 byte block of data in four 512 byte TCP segments. The first three arrive immediately, but due to some networking issue the last packet is lost and needs to be retransmitted. In the mean time you have already executed the `while (lenght != 0)` check and ended the loop. *After* that the last 512 byte piece arrives, but you have missed it.

What you need to do is to replace the `while(lenght != 0)` for something like `while(IDontHaveAllTheDataThatIExpect && !timeout)`, this assumes of course that you either know beforehand how much data you will receive or that you can somehow detect the end of the data.

Comment: Assuming a TCP socket, this not correct. The socket is either blocking, in which case `0` length return only happens when remote has shut down sending and all data has been received, or it is non-blocking in which case it throws an exception when it can't receive. (See [Socket documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx)). Either way, the problem would be in that the receiver waits for shutdown of sending rather than processing the data that is received, so if the sender does not shut down the connection the receiver waits infefinitely.

Comment: @MicroVirus True. The fact is that I saw a similar problem but it was in an unmanaged library, where sockets don't seem to work in exactly the same way as in .NET. Hence my confussion.